# Using variable in with block in Python

Tags: python

In Python, can I use a long variable name in a with block to shorten the code I use within the with block?

i.e.

```
thisIsMyVariable = {"this": {"that": {}}}

with thisIsMyVariable["this"]["that"] as v:
    v["a"] = "a"
    v["b"] = "something else"
    v["c"] = "more"

print(thisIsMyVariable)
```

When I try this I end up with an **AttributeError: __enter__** at the end of the block.

Comment: `v = thisIsMyVariable["this"]["that"]`?.... and print `v`?

Comment: These are [context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and as such need "__enter__() and __exit__() methods that are invoked on entry to and exit from the body of the with statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of `with` must be a Context Manager type, which is an object, with `__enter__`, `__exit__` dunders. A dict (and other simple types) are not Context Managers and cannot be used as subjects of with.

You might consider just reversing the order of your code:

```
   thisIsMyVariable = {'this': {'that': {}}}
   v = {'a': 'a', 
        'b': 'something else', 
        'c': 'more'}
   thisIsMyVariable['this']['that'] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation of the error

The problem here is that you are using the `with` statement which is used for [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).

Here python interprets it as `thisIsMyVariable["this"]["that"]` would return a class that implements the `Context Manager` protocol, and calls the `__enter__` method of the context manager.

since `thisIsMyVariable["this"]["that"]` returns a dict, which doesn't implement the protocol, and don't have any `__enter__` attribute, you will get an AttributeError

### Solution

As Sayse already has commented, the way to solve it would be to create a new variable with a shorter name, referring to the same dict.

```py
v = thisIsMyVariable["this"]["that"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, there is absolutely no need to use a `with` block just to assign a new variable with a shorter name. However, if you really *really* want to, then you can do this:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tmp_var(v):
    yield v

thisIsMyVariable = {"this": {"that": {}}}

with tmp_var(thisIsMyVariable["this"]["that"]) as v:
    v["a"] = "a"
    v["b"] = "something else"
    v["c"] = "more"
```

Note that Python does not have block scope, so the "temporary variable" `v` still exists after the `with` block; it is no more temporary than any other variable.